# How to Use a Key Vault Secret in a Task Group Without Creating a Task Group Parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I have a task group in Azure DevOps that does the following tasks (among other tasks):

1 - Read secrets from a Key Vault

[image]

2 - Set/Update an application's setting to a secret from the key vault

[image]

```
[
   {
    "name": "Foo",
    "value": "$(FooKeyVaultKey)",
    "slotSetting": false
   }
]
```

The only parameter I want in the task group given the above tasks is the name of the key vault where it takes the secrets from. The probem is, since the second task uses a variable (which is set by task 1), the task group creates a new parameter called "FooKeyVaultKey".

I tried accessing the variables in different ways, but only using parentheses works.

```
$(FooKeyVaultKey) - works, but creates parameter
${{FooKeyVaultKey}} - doesn't work
${FooKeyVaultKey} - doesn't work
$[FooKeyVaultKey] - doesn't work
```

Comment: I gave up trying and moved this task out of the task group into the parent build which worked and actually felt like the better way to do it.

Comment: @RobertBrooker the problem doing it that way is that, if you have multiple pipelines using the same task group (like in our case), you would have n-pipelines to maintain if ever a change in parameter is made

Comment: Yes, that would be more frustrating, a bit easier in my case, I am just calling a task group multiple times in one pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple trick is to use a blank expression (microsoft calls it a macro syntax) nested in the variable expression:

```
$($()foo)
```

This way a parameter isn't created for the task group.

EDIT:
I noticed some inconsistent behavior where at times the app configuration would be set to literally `$($()foo)`.

Comment: Verified this in our pipelines and it works fine, but it looks ugly. Wish there was another expression that covers this scenario.

Comment: Really nice findings!

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I edited the answer. I don't find that this solution provide consistent results. Unless someone does thorough testing or provides a better solution, I think it's better to keep this thread going for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible what you are trying achieve. This is written in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops)

> All the '$(vars)' from the underlying tasks, excluding the predefined variables, will surface as the mandatory parameters for the newly created task group.
>
> For example, let's say you have a task input $(foobar), which you don't intend to parameterize. However, when you create a task group, the task input is converted into task group parameter 'foobar'. Now, you can provide the default value for the task group parameter 'foobar' as $(foobar). This ensures that at runtime, the expanded task gets the same input it's intended to.

Comment: That's what I did in the mean time. If there was a complex variable `$($(foo)bar)` where the value of "foo" is blank, the runtime would try to look for a variable $(bar). This also wouldn't create a task group parameter. I figured if this scenario exists, then there has to be an expression that wouldn't create a parameter.